# Imported project from git into eclipse shows error in each line

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working in linux with eclipse.I imported a java project into eclipse from git. After the import from git eclipse is showing error in every line.I tried searching about error but I think it is rare one.

can someone please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: Sounds like your libraries are not configured for the project... was this a maven project or just raw source?

Comment: Is your java_home set in classpath ?

Comment: @Swagatika I tried creating and running a new project in eclipse. It run without any error

Comment: ok. so there was no issue.

Comment: @cjstehno Sorry I dont know what maven is but the project has been written in eclipse on my desktop. It worked fine there